# Remove a telnet hacker

Tags: telnet

I have an attacker who got into my router; he seems to have hacked the Telnet client protocol.

I previously had a Thompson & a Belkin. Both got hacked, Now I have a Netgear 4 cg3000v2 . Optus keeps sending me a new one, cause they keeps getting hacked. The settings I have put up are really strong, yet the attacker keeps getting in.

I added the MAC address to the filters but that doesn't do anything. It's like cologned in my devices. I no it might sound weird but it's true. He is also sending viruses to any device that connects to my router, including iPhones. I've had 6 routers already an I've taken my devices back many times but no matter what I do I can't stop it. I've even blocked ports he uses but he he opens more up.

I have a number of pictures, but do not have enough points to upload them here. You can see them here:
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30194073-What-s-going-on-Cracker-hacker-Opened-ports

Anyone no how to remove him from my router? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: there are many ways you can prevent him from accessing your router via access list or mac filter if you know the attacker mac address .

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  You haven't provided anywhere near enough detail.

Comment: I added the MAC address but doesn't do anything. It's like cologned in my devices. I no it might sound weird but it's true. He is also sending viruses to any device that connects to my router, including iPhones. I've had 6 routers already an I've taken my devices back many times but no matter what I do I can't stop it. I've even blocked ports he uses but he he opens more up.

Comment: i think your router firmware is vulnerable what is your router model or catalyst please add more details in your question again ACL can solve your problem ?

Comment: Netgear cg300v2 I have heaps of pictures that will pretty much say everything, but I don't no how to send pics on this app.

Comment: I had a Thompson & a belkin both got hacked, an 4 cg3000v2 Optus keeps sending me a new 1, cause keeps getting hacked the settings I have put up r really strong, yet keeps getting in.

Comment: but are you sure your pc is safe enough all these devices are hacked and you not ?

Comment: I don't have a comp right now they all got destroyed. I have a new MacBook I got yesterday not gonna use it until this problem is resolved the last Mac I got lasted 7 days an the 1 before that lasted 4 days thank god for warranty lol so I'm using my phone right now. I am hacked every device that is on the router are infected an hacked. An every time I call someone they say I can't do this. U need a hacker to remove a hacker. So I'm pretty much stuck right now. I don't no any hackers.

Comment: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30194073-What-s-going-on-Cracker-hacker-Opened-ports pictures are there I asked dslreport uploaded pictures not all of them though. There is a device connected to my internet. It is using my routers ip an the port it has opened is telnet. There is also an unknown ip using other ports. Don't no how to remove is I tried blocking the Mac addresses doesn't do any good though

Comment: Welcome, @user80770! I have edited your comments into your question. I believe this will make it better received. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. Click on the "edited ... ago" link to go to the edit history - you will find the rollback option there. Meanwhile, I hope my edit will help you. You can edit further information into your post by clicking the "edit" link under your post - that works better than comments. Good luck, hope your problem will be solved soon!

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe the issue suggests that not the routers are problematic(though many are questionably secure, it is highly unlikely that all models you've used up to now have been compromised).

Try disconnecting the router from the Internet, update its firmware(if possible) and verify all devices within the LAN for any signs of compromise(unexpected connections to remote hosts on non-standard ports, abnormal network activity, etc.).

Comment: I have replaced all devices an routers an changed service providers. I can't upgrade Optus firmware that's why they keep sending me new routers it isn't the devices netgear always says telnet user logged in  or out. The devices r infected because of him.

Comment: "Sanitize" those devices.

Comment: I have replaced them all have warranty doesn't do a thing new router new devices doesn't get rid of him?? That's why I need to no how else to remove him

Comment: I have been through 5 MacBooks 3 iPhones an 3 iPads an 1 dell Comp my ps4 has been changed twice he's destroys everything an every keeps getting replaced

Comment: New mac haven't even called Optus to connect router to internet I went to home page of router an it ales ready said telnet user logged in only had the Mac for 5 minutes nothing else connected to the new router.

Comment: What credentials(user/password) are you using? Are they the default ones on the router? On the devices behind the NAT do you employ a secure password policy(i.e. 12 random character passwords)?

Comment: Wpa2 every password is changed I have made the settings very good nat isn't there anymore cause he is using it everything he uses doesn't show up on my end anymore but every time I talk to someone they tell me my settings are really good it's almost impossible for someone to hack it so I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Look at this http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30194073-What-s-going-on-Cracker-hacker-Opened-ports

Comment: Ssid is disabled also always use vpn

Comment: Do you have windows installed on a mac? If so purge everything and reinstall.

Comment: Na no windows on it mac only last few days have taken it back 4 times already never installed windows on it only wine bottler to get malware bytes to see if it is gone but he's viruses r there still every virus he add isn't detected on the pc just destroys everything I have

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should give all your devices to a professional cleaning service company. They will get rid of everything.

Then, with a new router, set the settings before connecting to the Internet. Set a very long password with wpa2. (20 letters at least).

On the computers, block the telnet port and turn telnet services off (or tell the guys at the cleaning company to do it). Install Antivirus software on each computer and phone.

Later, after turning on the router, connect with only one computer and see if everything is good and if it doesn't get hacked.

If it's OK, you can start using the other computers. I think this way you should be good to go.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26290/discussion-on-answer-by-cube-remove-a-telnet-hacker).

Answer (score 0):

On windows I used zone alarm then went to Commodo on mac I use little snitch anti virus I have used them all nun of them do anything I have tried everything doesn't do a thing he's smarter then that